# Display all loop values in textbox

Tags: php, loops, textbox

How can i get  loop output in textbox. I get only last one value.  I know this is because textbox it out of loop. I can echo all values in side loop and get  the echo result but want them to show all values in textbox. 
I am using php for loop.

The input will be domain.com|phone|email  these will be more than 2000 values.

And i want output like this. Scrpated vlaue for input domain.com ==> phone ==> email but this should up in second textbox.

```
<?php

$post_list  = array();

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    //$txturl = preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', rtrim($_POST['links'],'/'));
     $input_list =  preg_replace('/\n+/', "\n", trim($_POST['urllist']));

    $input_list = explode("\n", $input_list);
    shuffle($input_list);



        for($i=0;$i<count($input_list);$i++) {


            $post_list = (trim($input_list[$i]));
            $user_info = explode('|', $post_list);
            $user_info[0];
            $user_info[1];
            $user_info[2];

            //I want $outputlist result in another textbox. 
            echo $outputlist = 'Scrpated vlaue for input' . $user_info[0]. '==>' .$user_info[1] . '==>' . $user_info[2] . '<br>';
        }
}   
?>


<form method="POST" action="date.php">
<textarea name = "urllist" rows ="20" cols="150" placeholder="Past Urls here! domain.com|phonenumber|email@address.com"><?php if(!empty($_POST["urllist"])) { echo $_POST["urllist"]; } ?></textarea>   
<textarea name = "output" rows ="20" cols="150"  > <?php echo $outputlist;  ?></textarea>   
<br/><br/>
<center>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate">
</center>
</form>
```

Comment: can you make a php variable inside the loop, concatenate it each time then set the textbox value to that concatenated string?

Comment: A code snippet or two would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this `echo $outputlist =` with `echo $outputlist .=`
and use `/n` instead of `<br>` for creating new lines in textarea..

Hope that it helps..

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I hope I get the point correctly. If my answer is not an answer to your question, then please explain more.

```
$value = '';
$array = array('foo', 'bar');
foreach($array as $arr) $value .= $arr.', ';
echo '<input type="text" value="'.trim($value, ', ').'">'; // It shows foo, bar in the input.
```

Comment: thats along the lines of what I was thinking